# Ecliptic line data

Tags: celestial-mechanics, ecliptic

I would like to get the data of ecliptic line with respect to celestial equator for a particular day.
Is there any specific URL that can give me this. I only have data for declination of Sun and the other planets and i dont think i could construct data of the ecliptic line from that. Any help on this would be appreciated. Please apologise if this question is really vague and not clear.

Comment: What sort of timespan are you interested in? The [obliquity of the ecliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic#Obliquity_of_the_ecliptic) changes slowly.

Comment: May be my question is wrong? i need daily data of full ecliptic line that covers the earth wrt latitude and longitude.

Comment: You said `the data of ecliptic line with respect to celestial equator for a particular day`. As @PM2Ring notes, the ecliptic is pretty much fixed with respect to the celestial equator. To a good approximation, it's simply a sine wave with respect to the equator, with amplitude of about 23.44 degrees, the 0 crossings at 0h and 12h, the max value at 6h and the min value at 18h. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun gives formulas for the position of the Sun and the path of the Sun is, by definition, the ecliptic.

Comment: How can i draw one when Sun is at different declination. Say today it is at -20, any example will be helpful. thanks for your help